# How can I change java class name to two words?

Tags: javascript, android

(Edited) I am very new to android development. Here is my question:
How can I change a java class name to become (two words)?

My main menu has 3 options, each is a java class:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = { "Report","Study","Contact",};
```

In order to change the names on my main menu, I have to change the corresponding java class name. I need the first one,for example, to be [Report Odor] instead of [Report].

I tried the following: 
Right click on the class and select "Refactor->Rename". But that gives an error if I have space between the two words.

Am I doing this right? Any help will be greatly appreciate it.
Regards. Here the complete code the my main menu:
    package com.reportodor.mohamed;

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String displayNames[] = { "Report Odor","Study","Contact",};
Class activities[] = {Report.class, Study.class, Contact.class};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, displayNames));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = displayNames[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.reportodor.mohamed." + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You can't use two words separated with a space as Java class name.

Comment: I don't see a class name here. Do you have the classes somewhere? In the given code you could just replace "Report" by "Report Odor". So either your code sample is irrelevant or you have there a misunderstanding

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I mentioned, I am new to coding so some of my explanations might not be accurate. When I change, for example, "Report" to "Report Odor", the new name does appear on my list app, however, it does not work. Basically, when I click, nothing happens!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I change a java class name to become (two words)?

If by "(two words)", you mean having a space in there, that is not supported in Java (or any other programming language that I can think of).

> In order to change the names on my main menu, I have to change the corresponding java class name.

No, you need to have the display name for the user shown in your `ListView` be different than the Java class name.

For example:

```
String displayNames[] = { "Report Odor","Study","Contact"};
Class activities[] = {Report.class, Study.class, Contact.class};
```

Your `ArrayAdapter` for your `ListActivity` would show the `displayNames`. Your `onItemClick()` method would look up the corresponding `Class` in `activities`, based upon the supplied `position`, and use that to construct the `Intent` to launch that activity.

Note that I am guessing that these classes are activities. If that is not the case, the same recommendation holds, but the details will differ.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, CommonsWare. As you suggested, I did add the displayName to my code. Also changed [classes] to [displayNames] in my ArrayAdapter. However, when I click on, for example, [Report Odor] in my app, It did not do anything. I'm not sure what I should change also!! Complete code is above. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MohamedEltarkawe: Replace `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.reportodor.mohamed." + cheese);` with `Class ourClass=activities[position]`.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH - CommonsWare. It worked very well. I really appreciate your help.